# Populating a textarea with database records

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

I populated a textarea with database records using:

```
<textarea name="textarea" cols="200" rows="20"> <?php 
     echo "Player Id\t";
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resourcebuilt)) {
               echo stripslashes($row['playerid']);
               ....;
               ....;
           } ?>
```

But this isn't exactly 100% what I need. I need to display records in what I believe is a textarea maybe not. But the records need to be clickable so I have functionality to those records (such as edit, delete, or even add a new record to database). Something like what admin panel contains.

I search SO and the web for something similar but with no luck. So does anyone know if this is possible with `<textarea> </textarea>` or do I need to using something like JavaScript or something related for the interactive functions? If possible provide examples. Thanks you.

Comment: You can use javascript event "onclick" to make **all** the textarea clickable

Comment: textareas are JUST for plain text. you can't "click" on things in them, you can't have stuff "happen" based on what's in the textarea, etc... they're just a dumb box with some text that you can move around in and change. you CAN layer on javascript to make things happen, but that's not what textareas are for, really.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is populate a multiline select:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp (sorry for w3 schools).

Your code for this would look more like:

```
<select multiple id="player-id-select">
    <?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resourcebuilt)) {
                   echo '<option>'.stripslashes($row['playerid']).</option>;
                   ....;
                   ....;
               } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Any other interaction (like clicking or whatnot) is done client side via javascript/jQuery:
http://jquery.com/